# Script to extract a range of lines from a file in bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell, solaris

I have this code

```
week=`date +%V_%d`
date=`date +%d%m%y`

#Cat to a file


        let tamano=`cat Prenum`
        file="White_prepago_${date}.txt"
        name="base_prepago_paqu_w$week_"
        cat WhiteList.txt | grep ",0" | sed '/^57/!s/^/57/'  | awk '{FS=","}{print $1}'> $file



# the number of lines of the file
let numlines=$2
#Must begin in the line in the file
let lines=$tamano+$2

num=$3


for ((i=1; i<=$num; i++))
do
   let d=$4+$i
   cat $file | head -$lines | tail -$numlines > base_$d
   let lines=$lines+$numlines

done
let lines=$lines-$numlines
echo $lines>Prenum
```

I am executing this code in a VM with Linux and works, and now i am intenting run this code in a Solaris Machine but not works, In solaris the file run but not works fine because create the number of files that i write but all my files are the seim, and in linux create all my files but with the increment.  The code have to split a file in the lines that i write

for example

```
 bash script.sh 5000 3 0
```

This code create 3 files of 5000 lines since base_1 from the file: base_prepago_paqu_w$week_". I am not using split because i need read the number in the file Prenum or Posnum.

In the file Prenum there is a number

```
$cat Prenum
 5008971
```

And the code select a range of the file for example if the number is: 5008971 and 
i write `bash script.sh 5000 3 0`  the output are 3 files from the line 5008971+5000 to 5008971+15000.

Could you please help me with my problem?, or with other idea that works in solaris?

Comment: Check bash version on both Linux and Solaris `bash --version`.

Comment: Why do you sum the 4th argument $4 (in your example `bash script.sh 5000 3  0` it is NULL) and the $i to obtain the "d" value?